# protractor web-driver with selenium on linux

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I have the following setup:

protractor running from a windows vm using a stand alone selenium server on a linux headless box.

The idea was to have chrome installed on my windows vm and to have protractor use this chrome install to run the tests via the selenium on the linux box. I start the selenium server on the linuxx box using webdriver-manager start.

When I run the tests from the VM I get the folloiwng error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 134 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0',java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:139)
        ... 14 more
10:39:09.119 WARN - Exception: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 134 milliseconds
java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

In my protractor conf I it configured to use the selenium standalone server by specifying the selenium url.

Any ideas how to resolve this and get the browser to be opened on my windows vm rather than the linux box looking for the chrome binary.

Thanks

Comment: Have you placed the chromedriver in linux box though?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the chrome driver into my protractor folder via web driver so in he folder I have  
cd nodejs/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/
---chromedriver                           
---selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
---chromedriver_2.14.zip